devops pipeline to copy a file within a branch
I am trying to use a devops pipeline to copy a file within the same repository and branch from one folder to another.
I use the standard task for copying files and afterwards a powershell script to commit and deploy those changes to the branch.
I don't understand why I get this failure message when trying to push the changes to branch:

This is the code I am using for committing and push:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: PowerShell Script
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: >-
      echo "commit all changes"

      git config user.email "abi@presales.onmicrosoft.com "

      git config user.name "ABI BI Build Service"


      git add --all

      git commit -m "Test Copy Files"

      git push -u origin HEAD:dev


As shown in your screenshot, the current git credential is missing the password, which is the authentication information to access your repo.

To resolve this issue, you can try the suggestions below.
Prerequisites: Change settings and permissions in Azure DevOps

Turn off “Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines” in Organization Settings -> Settings.
Turn off “Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines” in Project Settings -> Settings.
Grant version control permissions to the build service.

Option1: Use checkout task
Add a checkout task and set persistCredentials to true to leave the OAuth token in the Git config after the initial fetch.
steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/SourceFolder'
    Contents: '{Your target files}'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/TargetFolder'
    OverWrite: true

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "commit all changes"
      git config user.email "{Use email}"
      git config user.name "{User name}"
      git add --all
      git commit -m "Test Copy Files"
      git push -u origin HEAD:dev

Note: Ensure your current build is triggered from your dev branch.
Option2: Include an authorization header with a bearer token for authentication in your git push command.
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "commit all changes"
      git config user.email "{Use email}"
      git config user.name "{Use name}"
      git add --all
      git commit -m "Test Copy Files"
      git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" push -u origin HEAD:dev


Hi Ziyang,
sorry for the late response.
Your proposed solution worked fine for me.
I checked both and in the end I decided for the first one to choose.
Thanks for your help
Tobias
